# Nodejs, callback function

Tags: node.js, callback

I am trying to understand callback function concept.

Please explain what is the difference between two snippets of code

```
  //callback function

function greeting(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
}

function processUserInput(callback) {
    var name = "Johny1";
    callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

and 2nd one

```
function greeting(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
}

function processUserInput() {
    var name = "Johny2";
    greeting(name);
}

processUserInput();
```

why someone uses the callback function when the same thing can be achieved by simple function?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are not hardcoding the function. So, in future `processUserInput` can accept another function and it will work as expected.

```
//callback function

function greeting(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
}
function goodbye(name) {
    console.log('Bye ' + name);
}
function processUserInput(callback) {
    var name = "Johny1";
    callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting); // will output Hello Johny1
processUserInput(goodbye); // will output Bye Johny1
```

But in the second case the `greeting` function is hardcoded

So, you cannot change the `greeting` into anything without changing the `greeting` function's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Callback is designed for Asynchronous code if you mean simple function is synchronous. Its means not necessary to use callback on this simple function.